# How can I build a specific data structure?

Tags: paragraphs

I have a *Course* content type which has several "modules." (A module is just a name.) There are also several "units," which may or not belong to a module. A unit has several fields, for example *Location*, *Description*.

I have created a *Course unit* paragraph type, and a *Units* field in the "course" content type, which references this paragraph type. That way I can create units that belong to the course.

However, I'm not sure how to deal with modules. I could create a *Course module* paragraph type, but I don't think it would enable me to attach a unit to a module, since there's no way to select an existing paragraph.

Basically I need to create several modules inside a node, then several units, and optionally attach these units to one of the modules I've created.

Comment: Are modules unique to a course? Can units belong to multiple modules? Can multiple units belong to the same module? What's different about a unit if it's attached to a module vs not?

Comment: Yes, modules are unique to a course. Units cannot belong to multiple modules, but multiple units can belong to the same module. There is no difference between a unit that belong to a module vs not. In a way units are tagged with a module, so I've ended up setting up modules as a taxonomy vocabulary (with a content reference field that point to a course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you have done so far I would recommend:

- Create a "Modules" taxonomy.
- Make this a hierarchical taxonomy that includes course names (as if courses were top level modules) and then add the modules under those.
- Add a taxonomy reference field to your Unit paragraph
- This will be flexible in a couple of ways:

  - It will let modules receive descriptive fields as needed later.
  - It will allow site search and filter by module in a hierarchy that includes courses.
  - It will allow for modules within modules if that becomes a later requirement.

Optional improvements

- Make the module selector field on the Unit paragraph form use a view that filters by the current course name as parent (with depth)

Comment: Thank you, that's a great idea! I've ended up setting up a "course module" taxonomy (although I kept it simple, with just a name and course reference), and tagged each course unit with a term.